# Running "bundle update" tries to install production gems even in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I'm having a problem running bundle update with mysql2. I don't really need mysql2 in development, and it works in production, so I want to just tell my gemfile the following:

```
gem 'sqlite3', :group => :development
gem 'mysql2', :group => :production
```

Unfortunately it still says bundle update fails because of mysql2:

```
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.14), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.14'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Any reason why this is, and what can I do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to leave out production gems while you are in development because you want to be prepared for production from the development phase of your project in that you don't want unseen errors when you deploy.  That being noted, it's still possible to run `bundle update` without the production group.

Execute the following and you should see 'Gems in the group production were not installed':

```
bundle update --without production
```

For your case though, since you've already installed production group gems, you may want to clean your gems and install them as follows:

```
> bundle clean --force
> bundle install --without production 

# For test purpose
> bundle update --without production
```